# How does /dev/zero return a constant stream of zero?

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, dev-null

I am trying to recreate what `/dev/zero` does. I got a `/dev/null` driver working more or less, but can not quite see how to implement zero. My main problem is with understanding the "read" part.

The man page says:
 `Reads from /dev/zero always return containing zero ('\0' characters).`

Now the driver in `drivers/char/mem.c` shows the following function:

```c
static ssize_t read_zero(struct file *file, char __user *buf,
         size_t count, loff_t *ppos)`
{
    size_t cleared = 0;
    
    while (count) {
        size_t chunk = min_t(size_t, count, PAGE_SIZE);
        size_t left;
    
        left = clear_user(buf + cleared, chunk);
        if (unlikely(left)) {
            cleared += (chunk - left);
            if (!cleared)
                return -EFAULT;
            break;
        }
        cleared += chunk;
        count -= chunk;
    
        if (signal_pending(current))
            break;
        cond_resched();
    }
    
    return cleared;
}
```

The manuals for clear_user read:
`clear_user - Zero a block of memory in user space.`
I guess this is where the magic happens. So is reading zero "as easy" as to just write `0` to the userspace at `*buf`?

If not i guess my main question is: how do i force a driver to return `\0` when reading from the corresponding file?

Comment: "So is reading zero "as easy" as to just write 0 to the userspace at *buf?" - Yes, if the function registered as `.read` in `struct file_operations` fills the user's buffer with zero-valued bytes, then your device behaves like `/dev/zero`. If you want to know more about `.read` function and its specification, you may read e.g. the book "Linux Device Drivers" (LDD3).

Comment: Thank you very much, it's running! If someone is interested: I was able to make it work with copy_to_user() too, by "sending" a single 0. And i'll definitely check the book :).